# Why does my babel-chaining (&&) does not work?

Tags: firebase, babeljs, package.json

I`m doing a tutorial on server-side-rendering with React/Express/Firebase.

This tutorial was created in 2017 and unfortunately, I struggle on the script section with babel in which I try to chain some commands.
Please take note that each command for itself works fine, but chaining them leads to the following error:

> **Der Befehl "node_modules" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! nonssr@1.0.0 babel: `babel src -d functions/src && node_modules/.bin/babel index.js -d 
>   functions`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the nonssr@1.0.0 babel script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Thorsten\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-16T08_46_28_887Z-debug.log**

The script command is th following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "babel": "node_modules/.bin/babel src -d functions/src && node_modules/.bin/babel index.js -d functions"
  },
```

Is there a general mistake in this line of code?
Do you need additional code to analyse the mistake?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself, but maybe someone can explain why it is like it is.

This code works:

```
  "scripts": {
    "babel": "node_modules/.bin/babel src -d functions/src && babel index.js -d functions"
  },
```

I had to remove the second "node_modules/.bin/babel ...", just typed in "babel ..."